# Ionic 6 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: resolver.resolveComponentFactory is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I recently updated my ionic 5 Project to Ionic 6 and keep getting this Error when i run Ionic Serve.

Im not even sure where to look for the error because it worked before.

Comment: `ComponentFactoryResolver` is no longer available in Angular 14. If you use it in your code, you have to rewrite it. See also [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/25353).

Comment: Global Search gives no result for ```ComponentFactoryResolver``` so still no clue where I'm using it in my code

Comment: same error here - any news yet?

Comment: "@ionic/angular": "^6.2.1" solved it for me

Comment: any update on this? am facing same error now

Comment: Updating to "@ionic/angular": "^6.2.1" solved the it for me too, thanks @bastifix

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same error

ionic CLI 6.20.9
Angular CLI: 15.1.6

I'm doing an update but it doesn't run ionic serve and the only answer it gives me is
resolve.resolveComponentFactory is not a function

only reference I found was in ion-router-outlet.d.ts

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34129244)